# How can I manage my application's state in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, architecture, state

While practicing Ruby, I decided it would be nice to have some sort of state machine gem to help me manage the application state of a basic Ruby app (not using Rails).

I didn't find one, or didn't know where to look. So I wrote one.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines

Comment: @bjhaid Interesting, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem's name is **gk-application**, it's on rubygems and the GitHub repo is here: https://github.com/gregkrsak/gk-application

Basically, an application is an instance of `GK::Application`, which can then be in one of four states: `:stopped`, `:starting`, `:running` or `:stopping`.

The application's code lives in the event handlers attached to each state. To start the app, set its `state` attribute to `:starting`.

If you have the gem installed and would prefer to have a project template built for you, simply use one of the following methods:

Using `ruby`:

```
ruby -e 'require "gk-application"' -e 'GK::Application.new.project'
```

Using `irb`:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'gk-application'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> GK::Application.new.project
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> quit
```

Either of which will generate a file named `my_app.rb` in the current directory, containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'gk-application'


my_app = GK::Application.new


my_app.on_starting = Proc.new do
  puts 'Starting.'
  my_app.state = :running
end

my_app.on_running = Proc.new do
  puts 'Running.'
  my_app.state = :stopping
end

my_app.on_stopping = Proc.new do
  puts 'Stopping.'
  my_app.state = :stopped
end

my_app.on_stopped = Proc.new do
  puts 'Stopped.'
end


my_app.state = :starting
```

Which should get you started. Thanks for reading! Feel free to contribute to the code.